# Does Flink support repartitioning in the Table api?

Tags: apache-flink

The DataStream API allows you to set parallelism of each operator and choose repartitioning strategies (rescale, global, rebalance, etc).

Can you do the same in the Table API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Table API is a declarative API, where the planner and the optimizer generate the best plan for your business logic. You can't explicitly set these type of strategies there. The only exception are implemented SQL Query Hints, which allow you to alter the execution plan to a specific setting. These can be found at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/hints/#query-hints

Comment: Hey Martijn, I come from a Spark background, and it also has RDD which is a low level API and DataFrames which is high level and works on top of RDD, yet DataFrames has `repartition` and `coalesce` functions for changing parallelism. But I heard that you can get a DataStream from the Table API and probably set these settings there? Much like in Spark I can get an RDD from a DataFrame?

Comment: Hi Pavel, you can definitely switch between from/back DataStream and Table API, see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/